# Another lame question about getting the Legendary or Epic badge

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I have lame question #9237 about qualification for the `Epic`/`Legendary` badge.  As I understand it from reading other questions on this, that the criterion is a day where you exceed `200 reputation` by any means, not a day where you hit the `rep-cap`.

So, what about yesterday, for me?

I `rep-capped` at `100`, due to offering a `100 reputation bounty` on one of my questions, which I did when I noticed that I'd hit `200 reputation` really early into the morning.  After offering the bounty, I finished out the day at `145 reputation`, and had at least `49` "lost" `reputation` from `upvotes` that got `rep-capped` and did not provide reputation.

[image: Rep for the day]

So, does yesterday count towards progress to an `Epic` or `Legendary` badge, or not?  I `rep-capped`, but did not end the day with greater than or equal to +`200 reputation`.

Comment: How's your SQL? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58192/131874

Comment: @MarkHenderson my SQL's limited by the quality of data it's run against, and no offense to the SE staff, but that data is just not reliable, or live, so I'd be more trusting of a "this is how it should work" than a "this is how the data says it works.  This query."

Comment: http://serverfault.com/reputation <-- Go here, second to last line is `earned at least 200 reputation on X days`.

Comment: The less you concern yourself with the details the faster you will qualify. Think of it like a kettle coming to the bail - it's faster when you don't watch.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers  There is that, certainly, but not knowing the answer to this does seem to have put me back a day that I would have otherwise made some progress towards those badges - now that I know, I'll wait until a slow day I know I'm not going to hit 200 to offer a bounty ,should the need to offer one arise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [SQL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58192/189912) that @MarkHenderson linked to:

```
HAVING SUM(targetrepchange) >= 200) AS x
```

So it's clearly a delta. Sorry, you lose.

Comment: Must... resist... urge to downvote... for being annoyingly right... :p